# How to use unix and perl to open a website, enter text in a box, press "go", and save results?

Tags: perl, unix, web-scraping

Sorry for the broad question, but I simply don't know how better to describe this or even what the action is called. It is akin to a web scraper, but it interacts with the website too.

I'm not trying to do anything nefarious, I simply have 200 queries I need to do on a public website, and I really don't want to type them in one after another. Basically, I just want to use unix tools (lynx maybe? something like that?) or maybe some perl script to go to a website, enter text in the "search" field, press "go", and then save the entire page of results.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) and [WWW::Mechanize::FireFox](https://metacpan.org/module/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize::Shell -e shell
```

and then: get, fillout, open, submit. When you'll be done with the web interaction, do: `script` and save output to `whatever.pl`.

Example session:

```
$ perl -MWWW::Mechanize::Shell -e shell

(no url)>get http://google.com/

http://www.google.pl/>fillout
(text)q> [] depesz

http://www.google.pl/>submit
200

http://www.google.pl/search?ie=ISO-8859-2&hl=pl&source=hp&q=depesz&gbv=1>script
#!/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.0/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller;
use URI::URL;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
my $formfiller = WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller->new();
$agent->env_proxy();

  $agent->get('http://google.com/');
   $agent->form_number(1) if $agent->forms and scalar @{$agent->forms};
  $formfiller->add_filler( 'q' => Fixed => 'depesz' );$formfiller->fill_form($agent->current_form);
  $agent->submit();
```